# Maven dependeny on other other maven project

Tags: java, maven, gwt, dependencies, pom.xml

I have two Maven (GWT) Projects and one should depend on the other. I just added the dependency like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

The classes are referenced correctly and I can use them in my other project. But if I want to trigger a maven build, it complains with: "Could not resolve dependencies for project: Could not find artifact myGroup:MyArtifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT"

The project has no jar because it is an GWT Web application. It has a "war" file. I testet around with the  argument and tried values like "pom" or "war". It then does not show that error, but unit tests do fail because classes from the other project can not be found.

Comment: Are these separate projects or modules in the same project? Are you invoking Maven from an IDE or from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [define in the other project which is a war packaging things like this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#attachClasses):

```
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
```

This will create an artifact with the classifier `classes` which can be referenced in other projects like this (

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>myVersion</myVersion>
  <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: +1 but it's a workaround. I'd rather re-think the projects organization to have the WAR depend on a shared JAR.

Comment: That depends. If you have only a single maven projects which is the WAR than no. If you already have other components (multi module build) than yes.

Answer (score 0):

First call `maven install` for **MyArtifact** project that will create a jar and will place it in your local maven repository.

Now you can use `maven build` for dependent project.